# Could not find some components by calling findViewById

Tags: android, findviewbyid

findViewById can't retrieve a button and a radiusBar even though their id exists. code crashes when initiating saveButton or radiusBar.

acticity:

```
    private Button saveButton;
    private EditText titleText;
    private SeekBar radiusBar;
    private TextView radiusValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        titleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        radiusValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radiusValue);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    radiusBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.radiusBar);
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#00ffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myLocationText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/myMapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:apiKey="my google maps api key"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:padding="5dp" >
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/radiusText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="3dip"
        android:paddingRight="3dip"
        android:text="@string/proximity"
        android:textColor="#00ffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radiusText" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/radiusValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dip"
            android:paddingRight="3dip"
            android:text="@string/radius"
            android:textColor="#00ffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/radiusBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiusText"
        android:max="1000"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiusBar"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="@string/confirm"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i am new at android. even though i used old school comment out way or ddms i couldn't find why this is happening. thanks for the help.

Comment: after cleaning project my problem solved thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "crash", you should go on to say "... and this is the log output with the error message".  Anyway, the resource IDs certainly exist, as your code compiles. However, a common build system error with Android is that your resource IDs can be *wrong* after you reorder some XML.  I think you'll find that the error is a ClassCastException. The solution: clean your repo (e.g., with `ant clean`, or some button/menu in Eclipse) and recompile everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I had a similar problem, I usually could solve it by using the following menu in Eclipse: Project->Clean

You can see look at the class that Android projects automatically generate

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is a bit "too" smart in this case. It will find an ID that is part of any layout. Not just the one you assigned as the setContentView() layout.

So you have a valid ID, but it is not valid at runtime, when the layout does not contain the ID.

Comment: This problem is between aapt and javac, and will cause a crash even when setContentView() is given the right layout.